# How much does the bankers revolver cost?

Tags: high-noon-2

How much does the Banker's Revolver cost?

Answer (score 2):

The Banker's Revolver costs 50 wampum.

By the way, a question like this can be answered with a simple Google search, so next time do a bit of background research before asking.